# Look-behind requires fixed-width pattern issue

Tags: python-3.x

I have a regex

```
(?<=--my-service(\s|\t)*=(\s|\t)*")(.*?)(?=("\s\\\n)|("(\s|\t)*>>(\s|\t)*\/dev\/null(\s|\t)*2>&1))
```

and this regexp works at least on https://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html

with test data

```
--my-service="test-service" >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

it matches

--my-service="**test-service**" >> /dev/null 2>&1

However, when I try to run this very same regex with python it gives me

```
look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
```

Is there any way to translate this regex to python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what I did was I segregated chunks of regex to groups and then did something like this

\1\2my text\4\5